# Can a SPA have a separate page for different modules?

Tags: web, single-page-application

Background: I'm working on a project for an NGO and trying to build a website for them that works on different devices. Tech stack used: HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, Javascript, Java Spring(REST API), MySQL.
The website will only be used by the NGO.

Question: I'm thinking of building a Single page application but I feel that my page will get too cluttered since there is a lot of functionality that I need to incorporate.
So I was wondering if it is OK to have a single page for each module of the website ?

As an example, when the user logs in, a list of roles assigned to them will be displayed. When they select the role, the menu items corresponding to that role will be displayed. They can select an item and a web page specific to that item will be displayed and so on.
Say, there are 3 roles - Admin, Employee, Manager. Would it be Ok to create 1 page for Admin, 1 page for Employee and 1 page for Manager and treat each of the pages as an SPA?  So the Admin page would incorporate all the HTML and Javascript for the Admin role and the same would apply for the other pages.
In addition, there would be 1 page for login and roles. So a total of 4 pages.

I'm not a professional UI developer. So I apologize if my question seems trivial.

I tried reading up on SPAs but I was not able to find much related to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - nobody limits you from splitting your SPA into multiple Apps. You can divide your app however your want.

But you must understand why are you doing this?

The major problem with SPA is that your user must load whole app code, doesn't matter which page he opens.

If you can split your code into several SPAs, which will be much lighter than all code in one SPA, then it will have sense. Especially if you're sure some of these apps will be rarely accessed.

Another option you should consider - you can load some parts of the app dynamically on demand (https://medium.com/wolox/divide-and-conquer-lazy-loading-for-your-spa-32eb63149e76). Good example for this - if you have one page with the rich text editor which itself is a pretty heavy JS library, and you don't need to load it on every page, then you can move this library into a separate file and load on demand.

Comment: Thank you very much, Stalinko. Appreciate the help.